# Delete Dialog Navigation Prism Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

So I have a Confirm Delete Dialog and the expected behavior is that when they confirm, it navigates to the previous page. However, I keep getting a Null Object Reference Error on the Navigation Service or Parameters (I'm not sure which).

Code

```
  var p = new NavigationParameters();
  p.Add(PageConstants.UserId, UserId);

  if (!SalesLoad)
  {
    await _purchaseRepository.RemoveAsync(await _purchaseRepository.GetById(LoadId)).ConfigureAwait(true);
    await NavigationService.NavigateAsync(PageConstants.MyAppPageNav, p, useModalNavigation: false);
  }
```

Error

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
> 10-17 07:08:58.542 E/mono-rt (10291):   at Prism.Navigation.INavigationServiceExtensions.NavigateAsync (Prism.Navigation.INavigationService navigationService, System.String name, Prism.Navigation.INavigationParameters parameters, System.Nullable`1[T] useModalNavigation, System.Boolean animated) [0x00000] in d:\a\1\s\Source\Xamarin\Prism.Forms\Navigation\INavigationServiceExtensions.cs:47
> 10-17 07:08:58.542 E/mono-rt (10291):   at MyApp.ViewModels.DeleteLoadViewModel.DeleteLoad () [0x00199] in D:\My-App\MyApp\MyApp\ViewModels\Shared\DeleteLoadViewModel.cs:119
> 10-17 07:08:58.542 E/mono-rt (10291):   at MyApp.ViewModels.DeleteLoadViewModel.<.ctor>b__29_0 () [0x0001f] in D:\My-App\MyApp\MyApp\ViewModels\Shared\DeleteLoadViewModel.cs:92

The Navigation Parameters aren't null when I get the the Navigate line and neither is the object. I Set a break point in the VM that it's supposed to navigate to but it's never reached.

Comment: you can use `var navigationResult = await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("GoToPage");` to see the result of the navigation and a better exception message, or just wrap it inside a Try Catch

Comment: @RicardoDiasMorais It hits the error before it casts to the result